# i have a problem whith flask and python the problem is

Tags: python

```
from flask import Flask

app = flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
def home():
    return "Hello world"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

and in termianl send me this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xd\Desktop\python-anashe\index.py", line 3, in <module>
    app = flask(__name__)
NameError: name 'flask' is not defined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're importing the name `Flask` from the module `flask`.

That means you'll need (note the capital `F`)

```
app = Flask(__name__)
```

instead of lower-case `app = flask(__name__)`.